# Can't add friends on Google Chrome through a script, says this script is blocked

Tags: google-chrome, console

I have a script that adds members to a Facebook group, but I have a problem that the script is long, so I want to shorten it, so that's why I use a code that call it through a source file uploaded to server; the code is this:

`javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='URL';})();`

But the code is not working; it says:

> Refused to load the script 'My Script URL' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net
>   http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com
>   *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl 'unsafe-inline'
>   'unsafe-eval' https://*.akamaihd.net http://*.akamaihd.net".

What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [All JavaScript and all resources should be local (everything gets packaged in your packaged app).](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_csp.html)

Don't load the script from a server. Add it as a resource to your extension, and it should work fine.

Comment: Then minify it. You are not allowed to externally load scripts that don't work with the `https` protocol.

Comment: @ArsalHussain Don't make a Chrome extension.